# How to save output from the print function to a CSV file?

Tags: r, csv, printing

Factor-analysis,

```
print(fa1, digits = 2, cutoff = 0.5, sort = TRUE)
```

shows me a nice table in the console. How can I save this table to a CSV file?

I tried `write.csv` and `write.table` with various combinations of arguments, but all gave the wrong result.

This works:

```
fa1 <- factanal(x, 3, rotation="varimax")

sink("tp.txt")  #write all output to file tp.txt
print(fa1, digits=2, cutoff=.5, sort=FALSE);
sink()  #stop sinking, =sink(NULL)
```

However, I want all values/numbers separated by commas.

Thanks Tim, sorry if this is a duplicate, but answering a question with another method that I cannot understand doesn't help. I don't want to redirect output to a variable, but to a CSV file. `capture.output` is not what I am looking for.

Thanks dcarlson! Not sure how to make your suggestion work. 
Is there a way to pipe the output to RMarkdown and then use a knit function?

Comment: What is fa1? Include the full code.

Comment: The functions `write.csv` and `write.table` are designed for tabular data, a row of column names, followed by multiple rows of values, one for each column name. The output from `factanal` does not follow that format so it is not likely you can get it to work. You could start with the code from `print.factanal` (`getAnywhere(print.factanal)`) and use that to compute the values you need and then use `print`/`cat` to a file to produce something that a spreadsheet program could import.